# using useLocation state parameters all across the app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

sometimes in order to get certain values from previous page I use `state` of `use location` hook like this:

```
 navigate("/ListServiceConfer", {state: {name,family,Id}});
```

I should mention that I have to do this, since I can't store values like `Id` inside of localhost or creating redux store and using `useSelector` everywhere.

I wounder if there's a way to pass this state values all course the app? for example when I move from `listServiceConfer` to another route, I don't want to do the same thing all the time.

Comment: If you ask me I would store that value in a context, since you can't use redux.

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't pass data between routes so that they are de-coupled. You will have to opt for some kind of global state management (redux, or whatever you prefer), or if the values don't change often, you can also use React Context API